# MobX state tree - array of models doesn't trigger update

Tags: javascript, mobx, mobx-state-tree

I have following model:

```
 const AnotherModel = types.model({
    foo: types.string
 });

 export const SomeCollectionModel = types
     .model({
         data: types.array(AnotherModel),
     })
     .views((self) => ({
         getData: () => self.data,
     }))
     .actions((self) => ({
         fetchData: flow(function* fetchData() {
             try {
                 const data =
                     yield service.fetchData();
                 self.data.replace(
                     data.map((f) => AnotherModel.create(f)),
                     // Using plain json instead of create does the same
                 );
             } catch (err) {
                 console.error(err);
             }
         })
    }));
```

Then I have two React components, which I compose with `inject` and `observer`.

Parent one (view/page):

```
compose(
    inject((states) => ({
        fetchData: () =>
            states.myModel.fetchData(),
    })),
    observer,
)
```

Child one:

```
compose(
    inject(states => ({
        data: states.myModel.getData()
    })),
    observer
)
```

I have a re-rednering problem. Initially child component doesn't render anything. In the meantime data is fetched (action triggers itself). However data is not updated in child. `componentWillReact` doesnt trigger.
After changing routes (rerender by router) view gets updated

Do you have any idea? I'm stuck for hours.

Comment: what versions are you using? i switched to mobx-state-tree from mobx and have had issues described in their docs about nesting observers https://mobx-react.js.org/observer-component#nesting-caveat

Comment: also see this https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-state-tree/issues/1060

Answer (score 4):

1. You don't need to create a view to access your raw data, you can use the prop directly:

```js
inject(states => ({
  data: states.myModel.data
}))
```

2. You don't need to use `observer` if you use `inject`. MyComponent will observe what's inside the inject just fine:

```js
inject(states => ({
  data: states.myModel.data
}))(MyComponent)
```

3. In this case, you are observing the array, which is a reference. If you update the items of the array, the array itself doesn't change so MyComponent is not re-rendered. You could observe the array length, that way if the length changes, MyComponent is re-rendered, but it's only useful when you add or remove items from the array:

```js
inject(states => ({
  data: states.myModel.data,
  length: states.myModel.data.length
}))(MyComponent)
```

4. Finally, if want to observe changes to the items of the array even if the length doesn't change, you need to observe the items internally:

```js
inject(states => ({
  data: states.myModel.data,
  length: states.myModel.data.length
}))(MyComponent)

const MyComponent = ({ data }) => (
  <div>{data.map(item => (
    <MyDataItem item={item} />
  ))}
  </div>
)

inject((states, props) => ({
  foo: props.item.foo
}))(MyDataItem)
```